# How to retrieve data for two different portions of a single web page using LINQ from the same database table?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, ef-code-first

I am working on a project in `.NET MVC5` using code first approach, I have created a database table and I want to retrieve some specific records in two different portions (categories as of database) of Index page or (Home Page) from the same database table.

I have created the below controller which works fine for one of the portions named "Recent Events" but I am puzzled when I try to retrieve some records for the second portion of home page, suppose which is named as "Featured_Events" using the same controller?

Initially i just want the logic to work fine for the both portions,  but in case if an expert is reading my post, Then kindly also tell me how can i retrieve specific number of records in Featured Events portion, As you know that i am retrieving 8 records in Recent Events, what if i want to retrieve 12 records in Featured Events section?

This is the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     var result = (from i in _context.consult
                   orderby i.date_of_event descending
                   where i.category == "recent_events"
                   select i).Take(8);
     return View(result);
 }
```

Just for further clarification: In the view I use `foreach` loop to retrieve data:
As an example It looks like this:

```
@model Ienumurable <Example.Models.consultation>
```

CODE FOR RECENT EVENTS PORTION

```
@foreach (var recent in Model)
{
    if (@recent.category == "recent_events")
    {
        <p>@recent.date</p>
        <p>@recent.details</p>
    }
}
```

CODE FOR FEATURED EVENTS PORTION

```
@foreach (var featured in Model)
{
    if (@featured.category == "featured_events")
    {
        <p>@featured.date</p>
        <p>@featured.details</p>
    }
}
```

I would be really glad if anyone could assist me in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you have two lists of items you want to return, create a new class holding both lists as public properties, populate both in the controller and return the new class.

Your Model will now contain both and you can iterate over both using Razor.

example :

```
public class EventsDataModel
{
    public List<Event> RecentEvents { get;set; }
    public List<Event> FeaturedEvents { get;set; }

    public EventsDataModel()
    {
          RecentEvents = new List<Event>();
          FeaturedEvents = new List<Event>();
    }
}
```

your controller now  populates both:

```
public ActionResult Index()

    {
        var result = new EventsDataModel();

        result.RecentEvents = (from i in _context.consult
                      orderby i.date_of_event descending
                      where i.category == "recent_events"
                      select i).Take(8);
        result.FeaturedEvetns = whatever
            return View(result);


        }
```

Comment: Dear Andrei Dragotoniu, I really appreciate your response.
But using two lists means to have two different classes which further means to have two separate tables in the database.
This would create redundancy in data entry phase as both of the sections share the similar data but with the only difference of time and popularity. It means if date is recent it will go to the recent section and if featured is set to yes in the database table, then it will go to the featured section where rest of the data like heading and full description will remain same for the both sections.

Comment: And since I have spent a long time working on this logic, I think I am missing something in the LINQ part and it can be fixed by elaborating the LINQ query, what do you think?
Anyways, thank you once again for your kind response.

Comment: Anyhow today i was able to solve the problem using your logic, I slightly modified the database design via classes in Models directory and then applied your logic. Once again thank you very much sir, I really appreciate your kind cooperation.